# "lvalue required as unary '&' operand" in accept() socket system call

Tags: c, sockets, compiler-errors

I am writing a network program where, in the server part, I want to accept connections from multiple clients using a listening socket. So I declare an array of address structs like this:

```
struct sockaddr_in* client;
```

which I create using malloc and later on, to accept connections I type:

```
newsock = accept(fd_skt, (struct sockaddr *)&client[i], &(sizeof(client[i])));
```

and there I get `"lvalue required as unary '&' operand"` from the compiler. Can anyone figure out what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can't take the address of something that isn't an *lvalue*, that is an object with an address. The result of the `sizeof` operator is just a value, it isn't an object with an address.

You need to create a local variable so that you can take its address.

E.g.

```
socklen_t addrlen = sizeof client[i];
newsock = accept(fd_skt, (struct sockaddr *)&client[i], &addrlen));
```

---

As an aside, `struct sockaddr_in* client;` declares a pointer, not an array. To use `client` as an array you need to assign it to a dynamically allocated array at some point before the call to `accept`. I assume that this is what you are doing when you say "I create using malloc".

Alternatively you could actually declare `client` as an array.

```
struct sockaddr_in client[MAX_CLIENTS];
```

Comment: @Namratha: because taking the address of something that doesn't necessarily have a location in memory - and even if it does is just about to disappear from that location in memory - doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Charles' answer is correct, but one way to get around this kind of obnoxious function interface that requires a pointer to a value you plan to just throw away is to use compound literals:

```
newsock = accept(fd_skt, (struct sockaddr *)&client[i], (socklen_t[]){sizeof client[0]});
```

Comment: Funky trick, there have been dozens of times where this technique would've saved me a 'dummy' variable. I don't think I'll use this in the future tho, at least around here that trick is pretty much unknown and I'd rather not have colleagues tinker with this trying to "improve readability" or so.